# React-Redux removing(delete) an item on click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I am learning react-redux, so now I am trying to create react-redux crud app,  here is ny solution

Here is repo : [repo demo](https://github.com/throne1986/twitter-app)

The button

```
<span className="delete_info" onClick={() => deleteComment(comment.id) }>Delete</span>
```

The action creator to delete element

```
export const removeComment = id =>{
  return{
    type: ActionTypes.DELETE_COMMENTS,
    payload:id
  }
}
// delete comments

export const deleteComment = id =>{
  console.log('ids', id);
  return dispatch =>{
    dispatch(fetchCommentsRequest())
    axios.delete(`/api/v1/todo/${id}`)
    .then(response =>{
      console.log('yeees mom', response.data)
      dispatch(removeComment(id))
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      const erroMsg =error.message;
      console.log('eeeror', erroMsg)
      dispatch(fetchCommentsFailure(erroMsg))
    })
  }
}
```

Here is my reducer

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../action-types'

const initialState ={
    data:[],
    error:'',
    comments:[],
    loading:false,
    editing:false
}

const reducer = (state= initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_COMMENTS_REQUEST:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_COMMENTS_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading:false,
                comments:action.payload,
                error:''
            }
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_COMMENTS_FAILURE:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading:false,
                error:action.payload
            }
        case ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENTS:
            return{
                ...state,
              comments:state.comments.concat(action.payload)
            }
            
        case ActionTypes.DELETE_COMMENTS:
                return{
                    ...state,
                    comments: state.comments.filter(comment =>comment.id !==action.payload)
        
                }
        case ActionTypes.EDIT_COMMENTS:
            return{
                 ...state,
                 comments: state.comments.map(comment =>comment.id === action.payload?{
                     
                     ...comment,
                     editing:!editing
                 }:comment)
            }
            default: // need this for default case
                    return state 
    }
}
export default reducer
```

Now when I click delete, I see on the console the ID from action creators, but the element is not removed
and no errors, what is wrong here?

Comment: if you do console.log(action) right after case ActionTypes.DELETE_COMMENTS, and right before return, do you get anything?

Comment: @tachko let me check

Comment: @tachko I see nothing in console after adding console.log(action) as u suggested

Comment: do you get a network response from your axios request?

Comment: please add the code for `removeComment` function as well

Comment: @Siddharth I have added it check now

Comment: Do you see the comment inside `then` being logged?

Comment: Looks like you've not connected `deleteComment` with your component via `connect` HOC, you're just calling it like a normal function.

Comment: @Siddharth check my repo , I have added above

Comment: @Siddharth no nothing , check the repo above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few knots; I made this simplified sandbox (mocking an api call) of how it should work:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-minsky-99xi4?file=/src/App.js:0-799

index

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";
import App from "./App";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

App

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import deleteRequest from "./deleteRequest";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    comments: state.comments
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  deleteRequest: deleteRequest
};

let App = ({ comments, deleteRequest }) => {
  const makeDeleteRequest = id => {
    deleteRequest(id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {comments.map(comment => {
        return (
          <div key={comment.id}>
            <p>{comment.text}</p>
            <button onClick={() => makeDeleteRequest(comment.id)}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

App = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);

export default App;
```

reducer

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  error: "",
  comments: [{ id: 1, text: "test1" }, { id: 2, text: "test2" }],
  loading: false,
  editing: false
};

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "DELETE_COMMENT":
      return {
        ...state,
        comments: state.comments.filter(comment => comment.id !== action.id)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

async action

```
import deleteComment from "./deleteComment";

const mockAPI = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("deleted"), 2000);
});

const deleteRequest = id => {
  return dispatch => {
    const makeDeleteRequest = async () => {
      await mockAPI;
      dispatch(deleteComment(id));
    };

    makeDeleteRequest();
  };
};

export default deleteRequest;
```

delete comment action

```
export default function deleteComment(id) {
  return { type: "DELETE_COMMENT", id };
}
```

Comment: and I found the problem was I was not passing the delete function to my component the right way, this-> `function Dashboard(deleteComment){ return ()} ` solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not actually dispatching the action, you're just returning an async action creator (`deleteComment` function). In order your code to work, you need to first add [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware to your redux store (so that you can use async action creators) and then, in your component, when you're calling `deleteComponent`, you have to wrap the call using redux `dispatch`.

If you're using a function component, you can add `useDispatch` hook and have something like:

```js
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
// ...

function MyComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // ...
  return <span className="delete_info" onClick={() => dispatch(deleteComment(comment.id))}>Delete</span>
}
```

or you can just use the [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) function to create [a HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and pass the `dispatch` function from the provider's context:

```js
const ConnectedComponent = connect(undefined, dispatch => ({dispatch}))(MyComponent);

function MyComponent({dispatch}) {
  return <span className="delete_info" onClick={() => dispatch(deleteComment(comment.id))}>Delete</span>;
}
```